# Select Available Vlans in purchasing on Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing Vlan Selection on purchasing a virtual machine using Softlayer java API. 
The code below is what I have tested to list available vlans in a specific data center. It returns more available vlan list than "control.softlayer.com" does. 
Please find my test code below and let me know if you find any doubt.

Thanks

```
com.softlayer.api.service.Account.Service svc =
        com.softlayer.api.service.Account.service(client);


com.softlayer.api.service.network.Vlan.Mask networkVlansMask = new com.softlayer.api.service.network.Vlan.Mask();

// Router

networkVlansMask.attachedNetworkGatewayVlan().bypassFlag();
networkVlansMask.attachedNetworkGatewayFlag();

networkVlansMask.networkSpace();
networkVlansMask.primaryRouter().datacenter().id();
networkVlansMask.primaryRouter().datacenter().name();
networkVlansMask.subnets().id();
networkVlansMask.subnets().subnetType();
networkVlansMask.subnets().networkIdentifier();
networkVlansMask.subnets().cidr();
networkVlansMask.subnets().totalIpAddresses();
networkVlansMask.subnets().usableIpAddressCount();
networkVlansMask.subnets().ipAddresses().ipAddress();
networkVlansMask.subnets().ipAddresses().isReserved();
networkVlansMask.subnets().ipAddresses().virtualGuest();
networkVlansMask.subnets().ipAddresses().hardware();
svc.setMask(networkVlansMask);


Filter filter = new Filter();
filter.addFilter("networkVlans").
    addFilter("primaryRouter").
    addFilter("datacenter").
    addProperty("id", Long.toString(3l)); 

svc.addFilter(filter);

List<Vlan> vlans = svc.getNetworkVlans(); // All
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example can help you to get available `VLANS` during ordering: [SoftLayer_Product_Order::getVlans](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/getVlans)

This is a Rest example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/getVlans

Method: POST

Json Payload:

{
  "parameters": [
    265592,
    46,
    "port_speed=100"
  ]
}

Where: 
“265592” is the” loactionId”
“46” is the“PackageId”
```